# Windows 7 not staying in audit mode after reset

Tags: windows-7, wds, windows-audit-mode

I am creating a custom image for WDS distribution and I'm having some difficulty, I can boot the reference machine into audit mode during the oobe phase with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, but when I reset it (for installations and updates), it seems to go back into oobe mode and prompts an error saying:

> Windows could not complete the installation.
>
> To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation.

My understanding is it should default to audit mode until it is told otherwise.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or what option or step am I missing?

Comment: FIXED! Telling WDS to NOT automatically add the computer to the domain has fixed this issue, thought the underlying mechanics and the reason why are still a mystery.